Determination of cutoff frequency for filtering
I would like to determine the choice of cutoff frequency for e.g., a second-order low-pass Butterworth filter using frequency spectrum analysis. For this purpose, I would like to implement Fast Fourier Transformation on my data using scipy.fftpack.
After transforming the signal, I smoothed the spectrum using a Savitzky-Golay filter and defined a threshold frequency as 5% of the maximal frequency of the spectrum. Subsequently, I defined the significant frequencies significant_freqs based on this threshold frequency. The cutoff frequency was defined as the maximum value in the list of significant frequencies.
from scipy.fftpack import fft, fftfreq
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
import numpy as np

#example data
np.random.seed(42)  
duration = 10  
fs = 500  # sampling rate 
n_samples = duration * fs #number of samples

time = np.linspace(0, duration, n_samples)
signal = (
    2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * 5 * time) +  
    0.5 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * 20 * time) +  
    np.random.normal(0, 0.2, n_samples)  
)

#method
freqs = fftfreq(len(signal), d=1/fs)[:len(signal) // 2] 
spectrum = np.abs(fft(signal))[:len(signal) // 2]

smoothed_spectrum = savgol_filter(spectrum, window_length=11, polyorder=2)

threshold = 0.05 * max(smoothed_spectrum)  
significant_freqs = freqs[smoothed_spectrum >= threshold]

optimal_cutoff = max(significant_freqs)

threshold_dB = 20 * np.log10(threshold / max(smoothed_spectrum))


print(f"\nOptimal cutoff frequency: {optimal_cutoff:.10f} Hz")
print(f"Threshold amplitude: {threshold_dB:.2f} dB")

Is this a sufficient way to determine the cutoff frequency? How should I decide on the threshold frequency expressed relative to the maximal frequency?

might be well received on the [dsp.se] SE

@ChristophRackwitz I have tried with a similar question there, without the code part

ah, there it is https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/95650/how-to-determine-the-cut-off-frequency-for-a-gaussian-filter-in-a-reasonable-way
